# Can I use a `mpfr_t` as both input and output argument?

Tags: c++, c, arbitrary-precision, mpfr

The question is very simple and direct, but I could not find an answer on the [documentation](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html). If I have

```
mpfr_t a, b;
```

Can I do something like

```
mpfr_add(a, a, b, rnd);
```

This would compute the sum of `a` and `b` and store the result on `a`. I don't know if this results in an aliasing problem, potentially invalidating the result, or if this is fine.

Comment: what is wrong with `a = mpfr_add(a,b)`?

Comment: @jonas_toth: everything? The interface of this function is `int mpfr_add (mpfr_t rop, mpfr_t op1, mpfr_t op2, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, it's in section 4.3 of the linked document.

> MPFR allows you to use the same variable for both input and output in the same expression. For example, the main function for floating-point multiplication, mpfr_mul, can be used like this: mpfr_mul (x, x, x, rnd). This computes the square of x with rounding mode rnd and puts the result back in x.